# Problem when we want to create (POST) an entity using symfony and api-platform

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I am developing a PHP application using symfony and api-platform and I have a problem when I want to persist data in database.

I need to create three entities namely Person, PersonCivility and PersonCivilityDetail. I have also personalized the Person entity so that for each Person entity, we can know its current civility. So I had to use the PersonCivilityDetailRepository Repository to perform SQL queries and which is injected into the constructor of the Person entity. And so this is where I have a problem when creating an entity. Here is an extract of the codes of the different classes:

**Person**

```
<?php

class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private ?string $firstName = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private ?string $lastName = null;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=PersonCivilityDetail::class, mappedBy="person", cascade={"persist"})
     * @var PersonCivilityDetail[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    private $personCivilityDetails;


    /**
     * @var PersonCivilityDetailRepository
     */
    private PersonCivilityDetailRepository $personCivilityDetailRepository;


    public function __construct(PersonCivilityDetailRepository $personCivilityDetailRepository)
    {
        $this->personCivilityDetails = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->personCivilityDetailRepository = $personCivilityDetailRepository;
    }

    /** 
     * others codes
     */


    /**
     * @return PersonCivility|null
     * @throws NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function getCivility(): ?PersonCivility
    {
        return ($this->personCivilityDetailRepository
            ->findCivility($this)
        );
    }
}
```

**PersonCivility**

```
<?php
class PersonCivility
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private ?string $abbreviation = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private ?string $wording = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=PersonCivilityDetail::class, mappedBy="personCivility")
     * @var PersonCivilityDetail[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    private $personCivilityDetails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->personCivilityDetails = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**PersonCivilityDetail**

```
<?php
class PersonCivilityDetail
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
     */
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Person::class, inversedBy="personCivilityDetails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private ?Person $person = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=PersonCivility::class, inversedBy="personCivilityDetails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private ?PersonCivility $personCivility = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private ?DateTimeInterface $createdAt = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private ?bool $isActual = null;
    
}
```

and **PersonCivilityDetailRepository**

```
<?php
/**
 * @method PersonCivilityDetail|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method PersonCivilityDetail|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method PersonCivilityDetail[]    findAll()
 * @method PersonCivilityDetail[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class PersonCivilityDetailRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, PersonCivilityDetail::class);
    }

    /**
     * @param Person $person
     * @return PersonCivility|null
     * @throws NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function findCivility(Person $person): ?PersonCivility
    {
        return ($this->createQueryBuilder('personCivilityDetail')
            ->select('personCivility')
            ->join('personCivilityDetail.personCivility', 'personCivility')
            ->join('personCivilityDetail.person', 'person')
            ->where('personCivilityDetail.isActual = :personCivilityDetail_isActual')
            ->andWhere('person.id = :person_id')
            ->setParameters(['personCivilityDetail_isActual' => true, 'person_id' => $person->getId()])
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        );
    }
}
```

These are my different codes. When I do a GET operation, I have no problem. It is when I perform a POST, PUT or PATCH operation that I have a problem. The returned message is as follows:

> Cannot create an instance of App\Entity\Person from serialized data because its constructor requires parameter "personCivilityDetailRepository" to be present

**How can I do ?**

*Also, I wonder if this way of coding is an appropriate way. Do you have a better approach?*

Cordially.

Comment: Injecting repositories (or any other sort of dependencies) into entities is absolutely not appropriate.  All kind of issues will arise besides serialization.  Think in terms of using factories for creating entities.

Comment: Okay **Cerad 7** !
Indeed, I understood right away that the approach I am using is not the best.
But, I want to move forward in the coding of my web application. I have been working with symfony a short time ago. How exactly could I do this using the factories as you recommend?

Comment: If you want to "move forward", remove the repository from the entity

Comment: @NicoHaase, @Cerad, 
I did a few operations:
- I deleted the Repository of the constructor of the Person entity.
- I created a factory (`PersonFactory`) in which I inject the Repository (`personCivilityDetailRepository`). I also created in this factory a function (`createPerson`) which returns a Person entity.
- I also created a service which indicates that if we want to create a Person entity, we call the factory PersonFactory.

**Now, I need to configure doctrine to use this factory. Can I have a solution?**

Comment: This sounds like something for `@ORM\PostLoad` - the event that is submitted knows about the EntityManagerInterface, and thus can fetch the repository

Comment: @UbaldK The thing to understand is that Doctrine uses reflection to create and initialize entities when the entities are loaded from the database.  Basically a one to one mapping.  So no you cannot tell Doctrine to use your factory during the create process.  Doctrine does not even use the entity's constructor.  I think you just need to take a step back and learn about entity relations.  You seem to be expending a considerable amount of effort for some unknown goal.

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you so much !
I was able to use the doctrine postLoad event to load some dependencies to my Person entity. There were also some changes in the Repository. But overall, your method was correct. **Thank you !**